# What does the following code mean?

Tags: environments

```
\usepackage{comment}
\newif\ifshowsolution
\showsolutionfalse

\ifshowsolution%
\newenvironment{solution}{\paragraph{Solution.}}{} %
\newcommand{\insol}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\notsol}[1]{}%
\else
\excludecomment{solution}%
\newcommand{\insol}[1]{}%{} ò
\newcommand{\notsol}[1]{#1}%
\fi
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you highlight the actual code portion of your question and click the `{}` icon above the edit box, it indents it 4 spaces in the edit window, which has the effect of displaying the result as code for the rest of the readers.  I already did this for you just now.

Comment: In brief: It shows some code if you ask it for solutions and show something else if not.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. a full LaTeX document starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

The following might be described in non-correct terms:

`\newif` initializes a new Boolean switch. The following `\ifshowsolution` is the name of the conditional.

`\newif` doesn't need its argument to start with `if` but everything else is obfuscating. The first two letters get removed and `true` and `false` appended for the switching commands. The complete name including the first two letters are the conditional.

From now on every time you write `\ifshowsolution` the following code block up until a matching `\else` or `\fi` (whatever comes first) is executed if the switch is true. If there is a matching `\else` everything from that point on to a matching `\fi` is executed if the switch is set to false.

Conditionals can be used nested. Therefore the "matching" in the above is important. For each `\if` statement there has to be a matching `\fi` else the code results in an error. The `\else` is optional.

`\showsolutionfalse` sets the switch to false, `\showsolutiontrue` sets it to true.

For the code between `\ifshowsolution` and `\else`:

`\newenvironment` defines a new environment. It requires 3 arguments:

1. the name
2. the code which should be executed on `\begin`
3. the code which should be executed on `\end`

In this case `\begin{solution}` should start a new paragraph called "Solution." and `\end{solution}` should do nothing. The stuff inbetween `\begin` and `\end` are a group, so commands which don't have a global effect have no effect on the rest of the code outside that group.

`\newcommand{\insol}[1]{#1}` defines a new command which requires an argument and just returns its argument without further addo.

`\newcommand{\notsol}[1]{}` defines a new command which requires an argument but returns nothing.

In the `\else`-branch the effects of `\insol` and `\notsol` get exchanged and the environment called `solution` gets defined as a comment based on the `comment` package, so everything inbetween `\begin{solution}` and `\end{solution}` has no effect at all.

Does this describe everything you want to know?